# Pos printer emulator for mac

Tags: macos, emulation, point-of-sale, javapos

Does anybody know some emulator to test a JavaPOS application on MAC OSX?  (I need to be able to test some printing stuffs)

I tried http://code.google.com/p/pos-device-simulator/ but I couldn't install it.

Answer (score 0):

iOS Simulator comes with a printer simulator. You can start the print server from "file" menu.